# Retornar objeto selecionado em datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho a seguinte parametrização do meu datagridview:

```
    List<ModelAluno> alunos;
    ModelAluno aluno = new ModelAluno();

    public PesquisaAluno(List<ModelAluno> alunos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.alunos = alunos;

    }

    private void PesquisaAluno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfiguraDataGrid();

        foreach (var aluno in alunos)
        {
            dg.Rows.Add(aluno.Nome, aluno.Cpf, aluno.Matricula.IdCurso);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ConfiguraDataGrid()
    {
        dg.Columns.Add("dg_Nome", "Nome");
        dg.Columns.Add("dg_Cpf", "CPF");
        dg.Columns.Add("dg_Curso", "Curso");
        dg.ReadOnly = true;
        dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dg.Columns)
        {
            if (column.DataPropertyName == "Nome")
                column.Width = 300; //tamanho fixo da primeira coluna

            column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }

    }
```

No caso, eu estou recebendo uma lista de alunos de um outro formulário e apresento no meu datagridview apenas os campos que eu quero (nome, cpf e idcurso).

No método CellContentClick eu preciso retornar o aluno selecionado para o meu formulário anterior, mas não posso retornar apenas esses tres campos, eu preciso retornar o objeto montado (que é recuperado, inicialmente, em uma pesquisa no SQL Server e que já está armazenado na lista recebida no datagridview)

Como faço para retornar o objeto inteiro? 
Além disso, como faço para que, ao pressionar enter, eu selecione o objeto que eu quero e apresente nas textbox do formulário anterior?

Comment: pq só não fazer: `dg.DataSource = alunos;` ?

Comment: O datasource vai preencher campos que eu não quero apresentar no datagridview, então eu optei pela seleção manual das colunas

Comment: defina `dg.AutoGenerateColuns = false;` adicione as colunas que quer manualmente (como já fez) e é só definir o `DataPropertyName` (como também já fez)

Comment: Certo, e como eu posso recupero o objeto montado pelo datasource? É meu primeiro projeto com datagridview e estou com certa dificuldade

Comment: poderia ser algo como `ModelAluno obj = alunos[dg.SelectedRows[0].Index];` mas também tem outras formas

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem... Usando o datasouce e o `dg.AutoGenerateColuns = false;`, o datagridview apresenta as colunas que parametrizei, mas sem dados dentro. Não consegui setar o valor dessas linhas com base no `DataPropertyName`. Como seria isso?

Comment: `DataPropertyName` tem que ser igual ao nome da propriedade (Nome, Cpf, Matricula.IdCurso) etc... depois é só colocar a List como source

Comment: column.DataPropertyName = "Nome";

column.DataPropertyName = "CPF";

column.DataPropertyName = "Curso";

Seria mais ou menos assim? Dentro do foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudando um pouco se `DataGridView`:

```
List<ModelAluno> alunos;
ModelAluno aluno = new ModelAluno();

public PesquisaAluno(List<ModelAluno> _alunos)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.alunos = _alunos;
}

private void PesquisaAluno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfiguraDataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = this.alunos;
}

private void ConfiguraDataGrid()
{
    //Essa parte você pode fazer pelo design do visual studio

    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "Nome", Name = "columnName", DataPropertyName = "Nome" });

    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "CPF", Name = "columnCpf", DataPropertyName = "Cpf" });

    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "Curso", Name = "columnCurso", DataPropertyName = "Matricula.IdCurso" });

    dg.ReadOnly = true;
    dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
}
```

Evento double click:

```
private void dg_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, CellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    aluno = alunos[e.RowIndex]; //o aluno que vocÊ clicou foi esse
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo! Mais uma duvida: No caso, o objeto está sendo montado corretamente ao clicar na celula. Porém, eu conseguiria montar esse objeto pressionando ENTER também? Pelo que vi, o evento KeyDown não possui a propriedade RowIndex para eu setar.

Comment: no caso do enter, pegue a primeira linha que estiver selecionada: `dg.SelectedRows[0].Index` mas verifique se há linhas selecionadas antes: `if (dg.SelectedRows.Count > 0)`